# Problems setting up MySQL/MariaDB galera cluster

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, mariadb, galera

I'm a beginner at this so I apologize if this is a fairly simple problem.  I am setting up a Galera cluster using two RHEL6 vms.  The first node set up on vm no.1 went fine, but as I went to set up the permissions on vm no.2 with the following command:

```
mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT     OPTION;"
mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Can anyone tell me how I might go about fixing/troubleshooting this problem?
I am using the root account for the set up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you have both nodes in the cluster when you tried this? Because the message basically says that is expecting a password for the root user already.

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the password for root user and therefore you need to use new password during next logins. 
To enter password, use parameter -p
e.g. mysql -u root -p -e "your command"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;